# Which font is the best for reading text (not code)? I mean font that has the best readability

Tags: readability, font, ergonomics, health

Which font or type of font is considered the best for reading the regular text (not programming code)? Which font or type of font has the best readability?

Comment: On-screen, or print? If screen, what declared text size and what physical screen size/resolution? What do you mean by 'regular text' - a child's reading primer, daily news, a scientific treatise with lots of math, ...? As currently formulated, I think this question may be too broad to allow for a useful answer.

Comment: Even if all those details are given, the answer will still be opinion based.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Lots of text on monitor and on paper. Just text, not code not math, not formulas

Comment: This should be merged with: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/13218/easiest-to-read-fonts/13221

Answer (score 3):

There is a old rule that says: "Use sans serif fonts for screens". In the 90s this rule was true because the Screens were too bad to display the serifs (the small feets) correctly. Nowadays, the screens are bigger with a better resolution. So this rule kind of no longer applies .
Also the reading speed between differs mot much between serifs an sans serifs. However, users are used to Reader long texts in serifs (books, magazines,...). 
What to do now?
I think going for a too fancy font will have a negative effect. Also choosing more than two font families. Personally, i like "Open Sans" you can find it on Google Fonts. It's a very clean Font and goes well with other fonts. Also popular are "Roboto" or "Markazi Text".
The decision could also be more design or brand driven. 

Further Reading:
https://www.nngroup.com/articles/serif-vs-sans-serif-fonts-hd-screens/

Answer (score 2):

First of all, there is no "best" font for reading text. There are fonts that are great when the text is short, and awful when the text exceeds 2-3 lines.
Longer text that is considered an article can be more pleasing to read with a good serif font, while text that are considered to be instructions or UI text are better off as sans-serif.
While I was working on a dashboard I compared several sans-serif fonts and found out the Open Sans and Plex are much better than Roboto and other sabs-serif fonts